# Replace text in html?

Tags: javascript, replace

I have this code that gets the query string value and displays it in an `h3`. I'm tring to change any `%20`s in the url to spaces. I've tried using `.replace`, but it doesn't work.

```
 <h3 style="text-decoration: underline;margin-left:10px;color:white;position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;">
        <script>
            function frtitlen(frtitle) {
                frtitle = frtitle.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
                var regexS = "[\\?&]" + frtitle + "=([^&#]*)";
                var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
                var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);

                if (results == null) return "Untitled";
                else {

                    return results[1];
                }
            } 
        </script>
        <script>
            document.write(frtitlen('frtitle')); 
        </script>
    </h3>
```

Comment: use decodeURIComponent to decode escaped characters, easier than trying to use regexp to do so

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the the best option to replace repeatedly is  to use split and join functions together, split() function breaks the string into an array by a delimiter and join() function joins the array with your delimiter, replace() function replaces the text only once in the entire string.

```
    <script>
     //This is the best substitute for the replace repeatedly.
     str.split(delimiter).join(your_own_delimiter);
   </script>
```

Say for example you have a string and you want to replace the space with a hyphen, then you can replace all the spaces in it as shown below.

```
   <script>
   var your_string="This is my demo string.";
   output_string=your_string.split(' ').join('-');
   console.log(output_string); //Final Output: This-is-my-demo-string.
   </script>
```